# CS5.5 Flash Professional DEBUG help?

Tags: flash, debugging, adobe

I have somehow mysteriously changed my environment such that when debugging, it no longer brings up the actionscript window. While it seems to be debugging, I cannot step through code (or more accurately, see the line it is on) without this window, but for the life of me I don't understand how to re-enable this window. Hours of googling have turned up nothing.

How do you setup the debug script window for CS5.5 Flash Professional?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reset the Workspace using the "Reset 'Debug'" option which is available in the menu where you can switch the layouts? Hint: It's only available when you in debug view.

Comment: Aha, success. I had not seen the reset. Furthermore, I've discovered the cause of the error: I had previously minimized (by dragging up) the half of the debug window containing the "Scene/Symbol   Layer    Frame". Having not seen this window in AGES, and suddenly missing the code trace I did not understand that I had simply accidentally dragged the former window half off the bottom of the window in my layout, thus pushing the code trace portion off screen. A completely silly error, and I thank you greatly for your speedy and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, success. I had not seen the reset. Furthermore, I've discovered the cause of the error: I had previously minimized (by dragging up) the half of the debug window containing the "Scene/Symbol   Layer    Frame". Having not seen this window in AGES, and suddenly missing the code trace I did not understand that I had simply accidentally dragged the former window half off the bottom of the window in my layout, thus pushing the code trace portion off screen.